# Storing solution of equation and performing operation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following equations which I solve to find a and b.

```
rhohat = I*omega*v;
rhobar = I*omega*vbar;
lambdaplus = eta + zeta;
lambdaneg = eta - zeta;
lambdabarplus = etabar + zetabar;
lambdabarneg = etabar - zetabar;



eqns = {xi == 
    I*zetabar^(1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] - 
     I*zetabar^(1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3],
   tau == I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] + 
     I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3]} // Simplify;

sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b}][[1]] // Simplify

(* {a -> -((E^(x3 (-etabar + zetabar)) (-I omega vbar xi + tau zetabar))/(
   2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar])), 
 b -> -((E^(-x3 (etabar + zetabar)) (I omega vbar xi + tau zetabar))/(
   2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar]))} *)
```

My question is, how can I store a and b in their above forms, and then, how do I calculate the derivatives of a and b with respect to x3 when xi is x3 dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

```
Simplify[Solve[eqns, {a, b}][[1]]] /. Rule -> Set
```

For your second question: use `xi[x3]` instead of `xi` in your definitions from the beginning. Then you can do `D[a,x3]` and `D[b,x3]` simply:

```
eqns = {xi[x3] == I*zetabar^(1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] - 
          I*zetabar^(1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3], 
        tau == I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] + 
          I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3]} // Simplify;
Simplify[Solve[eqns, {a, b}][[1]]] /. Rule -> Set;
D[a, x3]
D[b, x3]
```

Comment: Thank you perfect answer. Could I also ask, how can I then substitute values for the xi'[x3] terms in the derivates? I tried using Simplify[aDx3, tau'[x3] == rhohat*xi + c64hat*tau], where I have called aDx3 =D[a, x3].

Comment: Have you tried `D[a, x3] /. xi'[x3] -> ...` where the ... stands for whatever `xi'[x3]` is?

Comment: Perfect! One more, how would I replace multiple variables via this method?

Comment: list of rules: `D[a, x3] /. {xi'[x3] -> AAA, tau'[x3] -> BBB, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b}] // FullSimplify

a = sol[[All, 1, 2]]

Da = D[a, x3]

b = sol[[All, 2, 2]]

Db = D[b, x3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write for derivative of a respect to x3

```
a3=D[a /. sol, x3]
```

for b

```
b3=D[b /. sol, x3]
```